# React Mapbox component flickering when I type in the input box of a different component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-component, react-state

I want to have a map and an input form on a single page. The user should be able to type into the input field, hit submit, and have the Mapbox component move to that location.

I have two issues, and I suspect they are related. When I type in the input box, the map component flickers after each onChange event. Second, when I submit the form, the geolocation is successfully fetched, the props are updated on the Map component and the map marker appears, but the map doesn't perform the neat animation I see when I just go into React Dev tools and manually update the props.

I know I'm a rank beginner, and there are a thousand things wrong with this I'm sure. I'd love if someone knows the answer to this, but I'd also be happy if someone could just point me in the right direction. I spend the morning looking over the React's "getting started" and "hooks" section, and took some React classes where you built simple apps, but clearly there was something fundamental that didn't sink in. Thanks!

Here is the NextJS page:

```
import ReactMapboxGl, { Marker } from 'react-mapbox-gl';
import 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css';
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function TestPage() {
  const Map = ReactMapboxGl({
    accessToken: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPBOX,
  });

  const [searchLocation, setSearchLocation] = useState('');
  const [geolocate, setGeolocate] = useState({
    coordinates: [2.61878695312962, 47.8249046208979],
    isPin: false,
  });

  async function fetchGeolocate(location) {
    const url = `https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/${location}.json?access_token=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPBOX}`;
    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
        }
        return response.text();
      })
      .then((myText) => {
        const json = JSON.parse(myText);
        const coordinates = json.features[0].center;
        setGeolocate({ coordinates, isPin: true });
      });
  }

  function handleInputChange(event) {
    setSearchLocation(event.target.value);
  }
  function handleForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetchGeolocate(searchLocation);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Map
        style="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11"
        containerStyle={{
          height: '50vh',
          width: '100vw',
        }}
        center={geolocate.coordinates}
        zoom={[3]}
      >
        {geolocate.isPin && (
          <Marker coordinates={geolocate.coordinates}>
            <span className="text-3xl" role="img" aria-label="push-pin">
              
            </span>
          </Marker>
        )}
      </Map>

      <form onSubmit={handleForm}>
        <div className="flex flex-col mb-4">
          <label
            htmlFor="search"
            className="flex flex-col uppercase font-bold text-lg text-gray-700"
          >
            Location
            <input
              type="text"
              name="search"
              placeholder="Location"
              value={searchLocation}
              className="border py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 block"
              onChange={handleInputChange}
            />
          </label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Find</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Also consider using the lodash library. This prevents requests from being sent every time someone types something in in quick sucsession. only after a tiny pause should then  fetchGeolocation request be triggered. https://lodash.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sense that the problems are related is right on. One issue is that you're re-initializing the `Map` component on every render:

```
const Map = ReactMapboxGl({
    accessToken: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPBOX,
  });
```

It's also going to keep animations from happening (I think) because it'll make a new instance of the Map, which will cause React unmount/remount the component.

### Edit: Answer from OP below: initialize outside of component

Looks like you can just initialize the component outside any rendering logic.

### Alternate approach: using state

In functional components, we want to put initialization logic in [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) (or if it's crucial that it happens **before** first render, `useLayoutEffect`).

```
const [map, setMap] = useState()
useEffect(() => {
  const mapInit = ReactMapboxGl({
    accessToken: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPBOX,
  })
  setMap(mapInit)
}, [])
```

The `[]` at the end is key. It keeps our callback from getting called after the first time.

To be honest, your component may be complex enough to warrant using a class component, where you could use `componentDidMount` for the initialization, and all those helper functions won't have to be recomputed each render. Ultimately it's up to you though.

One last note: you've declared `fetchGeolocate` as `async`, which means instead of calling `.then` on all the results, you can use `await` if you want. Or take away the `async` & continue to use `Promise.then`, it's up to you. [Mozilla's docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) might help clarify the difference.

Comment: Wow. This is all incredibly helpful. Wandering through the wilderness, it's hard to see when you've lost the trail. One issue I've had is that the instruction I've consumed is hook based, while the React-authored material is class based. It's clear to me now I'm not going to get away without learning both. Let me give these suggestions a try. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: What you suggested led me to the solution. I was not able to put Map into state, and not really sure that would be a good idea, as Map is a component in-and-of itself, and from what I gather components don't belong in state. Also, as far as I could tell I never needed the useEffect hook. Anyhow, thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

As @elhil said above, the issue was fundamentally that I was re-initializing the map on each render. All it took was moving the map component initialization out of the main function. I also took @elhil's advice and fixed my async await function. Code below.

```
import ReactMapboxGl, { Marker } from 'react-mapbox-gl';
import 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css';
import { useState } from 'react';

const Map = ReactMapboxGl({
  accessToken: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPBOX,
});

export default function TestPage() {
  const [searchLocation, setSearchLocation] = useState('');
  const [geolocate, setGeolocate] = useState({
    coordinates: [2.61878695312962, 47.8249046208979],
    isPin: false,
  });

  async function fetchGeolocate(location) {
    const url = `https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/${location}.json?access_token=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAPBOX}`;
    const response = await fetch(url);
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
    }
    const json = await response.json();
    const coordinates = json.features[0].center;
    setGeolocate({ coordinates, isPin: true });
  }

  function handleInputChange(event) {
    setSearchLocation(event.target.value);
  }
  function handleForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetchGeolocate(searchLocation);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Map
        style="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11"
        containerStyle={{
          height: '50vh',
          width: '100vw',
        }}
        center={geolocate.coordinates}
        zoom={[3]}
      >
        {geolocate.isPin && (
          <Marker coordinates={geolocate.coordinates}>
            <span className="text-3xl" role="img" aria-label="push-pin">
              
            </span>
          </Marker>
        )}
      </Map>

      <form onSubmit={handleForm}>
        <div className="flex flex-col mb-4">
          <label
            htmlFor="search"
            className="flex flex-col uppercase font-bold text-lg text-gray-700"
          >
            Location
            <input
              type="text"
              name="search"
              placeholder="Location"
              value={searchLocation}
              className="border py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 block"
              onChange={handleInputChange}
            />
          </label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Find</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```